# Can i include symbols in a password intended for HTTP basic auth

Tags: security, http, url, couchdb, basic-authentication

I'm using basic auth over SSL for CouchDB, and I was wondering, if there are symbols in my password, how do I get it working, and not colliding with the url in general?

For example: `https://username:p@$$word@couchdb.domain.com/db`

Any help would rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic auth uses the `Authorization` header in the HTTP request to pass your user name and password, not the URL.  The URL you have posted is a shortcut supported by some browsers (in which the browser converts the username/password in the URL into the appropriate headers).  The URL format is not actually part of the basic auth spec (see the RFC for more complete details: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt).

With that out of the way, yes, basic auth supports symbols and you should not need to worry about whether or not those symbols have special meaning in a URL.  However, the basic auth spec is ambiguous when it comes to charsets and contains no way to specify which charset is being used to encode the user name and password.  As a result, any character outside the 7 bit ASCII range may cause issues dependent upon the server side implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Basic Authentication RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617):

> To receive authorization, the client sends the userid and password, separated by a single colon (":") character, within a base64 encoded string in the credentials.

I don't understand why you feel you must send your credentials in clear-text as part of the URL, when [the official Couch DB documentation](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html) clearly suggests a more standard way of authentication.